# Are these functions convex functions?

Tags: functions, convex-optimization

$f_i(z) = f_i(x,y) = y_i^\alpha - x_i$, where $x,y \in R^n$, $z = (x, y)$, $\alpha \in R$ and $\alpha > 1$, $i = 1, \dots, n$.

Are these functions convex functions ?

For $f_i$, the gradient is $
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
\vdots \\
-1 \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
\alpha y_i^{\alpha-1} \\
\vdots \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$,

and the Hessian should be $
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots &  0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & & \vdots & &  \vdots & & \vdots\\ 
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots &  0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots &  0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & & \vdots & &  \vdots & & \vdots\\ 
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots &  \alpha(\alpha-1)y_i^{\alpha-2} & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & & \vdots & &  \vdots & & \vdots\\ 
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots &  0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$

So when $y_i^{\alpha-2} \geq 0$, it's a convex function?

Comment: Have you try to compute $D^2f$? Is it positive definite or negative definite ?

Comment: $det(D^{2}f)\geq 0$ and $Tr(D^{2}f)\geq 0$

Comment: How are you defining $y^\alpha$ for $y\in\mathbb{R}^k,\,k>1?$

Comment: @charlotte See my update please :)

Comment: You have to check the determinants of every principal minor, not just the determinant.

Comment: Definition of "convex" for a vector-vaued function?

Comment: @GEdgar I'm sorry for the strange question, please let me think a while...

Comment: Maybe I should modified the question like this to make all the definitions to the right way.

Comment: It looks right to me now

Comment: Please read Chapter 3 of Boyd & Vandenberghe. This is about the hardest possible way to prove convexity. Let me add: are you assuming $y$ is nonnegative? The short answer here is yes, these functions are convex for nonnegative $y$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks for your recommendation. And when $\alpha=2$, $y$ is no need to be nonnegative :)

Comment: That is correct. Or any positive even integer for that matter. For all other choices, though, you need to decide what to do for negative $y$, and that choice does affect convexity.

Comment: There is no need to build these huge gradients and Hessians, for one thing. Just consider the active variables.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Yes, you're right~